# Locally Hosted Website / Email went down. Website still works on localhost. Firewall, or PHP error?

Tags: php, firewall

I'm working IT at a small company. We host our own exchange servers, and web server. Yesterday, at around 2pm, external emails stopped getting through to us, and our website began serving a 500 error to everyone.

I didn't do much to the firewall (sonicwall 240) or the servers yesterday to cause this. We run WordPress and do not have automatic updates turned on. Also PHP did not update itself.

I'm not sure where to look first. Any ideas on how to track down what's throwing the 500 error? It's not a single page or script that's doing it. Even if I create my own .php file, it'll have a 500 error.

Comment: How about looking at the error logs to see what caused the 500 error?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. The error log was 2.5 gigs, and it took about 90 minutes to break it into readable chunks.

Comment: I think it's firewall related. I changed our windows server to redirect to google.com if anyone hits our website. When I typed in localhost, I was redirected to google, but when I went to our website via www.website.com it didn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Our web server lost it's internal IP address. I changed it back to 192.168.0.3 as it was before, and all is well.